# deserialize json to object with a dictionary System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json.net, system.text.json, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on a .Net 6.0 project, and I want to migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json. So far most is working, except the following:

I've got this json:

```json
[
   {
      "Key":"ValidateRequired",
      "LocalizedValue":{
         "fr-FR":"Ce champ est obligatoire.",
         "en-GB":"This field is required.",
         "nl-BE":"Dit is een verplicht veld.",
         "de-DE":"Dieses Feld ist ein Pflichtfeld."
      }
   },
   {
      "Key":"ValidateEmail",
      "LocalizedValue":{
         "fr-FR":"Veuillez fournir une adresse électronique valide.",
         "en-GB":"Please enter a valid email address.",
         "nl-BE":"Vul hier een geldig e-mailadres in.",
         "de-DE":"Geben Sie bitte eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse ein."
      }
   },
   {
      "Key":"ValidateUrl",
      "LocalizedValue":{
         "fr-FR":"Veuillez fournir une adresse URL valide.",
         "en-GB":"Please enter a valid URL.",
         "nl-BE":"Vul hier een geldige URL in.",
         "de-DE":"Geben Sie bitte eine gültige URL ein."
      }
   }
]
```

Which I am trying to store into the following:

```
public class Translations
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> LocalizedValue = new();
}
```

When I am deserializing using Newtonsoft.JSON, the dictionary gets populated just fine with the values from `LocalizedValue`

```
jsonlocalization = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Translations>>(jsonString);
```

but when I try to use System.Text.Json, the dictionary stays empty

```
jsonlocalization = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Translations>>(jsonString);
```

How can I use System.Text.Json and populate the dictionary?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `System.Text.Json` library doesn't deserialize to fields. If you change your class to use a property instead, your sample JSON will deserialize as expected.

```
public class Translations
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> LocalizedValue { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Comment: I had just come to the same realization and was working on a live demo to demonstrate - may as well leave this here now: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WvOaze

Answer (score 1):

`JsonSerializerOptions` class has [`IncludeFields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions-includefields) property which can be used to deserialize to field variables